# why does unicode(u'') passed an errors parameter raise TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

Using python 2.7.3, the following does not raise TypeError.

```
>>> unicode(u'')
    u''
```

But passing `errors` parameter raises `TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported`

```
>>> unicode(u'',errors='replace')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported

>>> unicode(u'',errors='ignore')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported

>>> unicode(u'',errors='strict')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported
```

***Any guesses why this behaves so differently?***   IMO, this is a surprising quirk to the `unicode` function.

---

Browsing python source code, (I'm just taking a guess that I'm following the correct code path)

1. in [Python/unicodeobect.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/unicodeobject.c?revision=82248&view=markup) in function `PyUnicode_FromEncodedObject` we find the error strings `"decoding Unicode is not supported"`.  The error string is set if `PyUnicode_Check(obj)` return non-0.
2. in [Include/object.h](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Include/object.h?revision=81029&view=markup) , `PyUnicode_Check` evaluates to the expression `(((Py_TYPE(obj))->tp_flags & (Py_TPFLAGS_UNICODE_SUBCLASS)) != 0)` ,

However, I could not find where the Python code takes a different code path due to passing the `errors` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

`unicode` in Python ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode)) is a function that converts a string to the unicode representation of the string in Python. However, the behaviour is different if you pass in the encoding or error parameters.

> If encoding and/or errors are given, unicode() will decode the object
>   which can either be an 8-bit string or a character buffer using the
>   codec for encoding. The encoding parameter is a string giving the name
>   of an encoding; if the encoding is not known, LookupError is raised.
>   Error handling is done according to errors; this specifies the
>   treatment of characters which are invalid in the input encoding. If
>   errors is 'strict' (the default), a ValueError is raised on errors,
>   while a value of 'ignore' causes errors to be silently ignored, and a
>   value of 'replace' causes the official Unicode replacement character,
>   U+FFFD, to be used to replace input characters which cannot be
>   decoded. See also the codecs module.
>
> If no optional parameters are given, unicode() will mimic the
>   behaviour of str() except that it returns Unicode strings instead of
>   8-bit strings. More precisely, if object is a Unicode string or
>   subclass it will return that Unicode string without any additional
>   decoding applied.

The reason that you cannot convert `u''` to unicode is because it is already a unicode representation. When Python tries to decode it with the ascii codec (the default codec, since you didn't specify one), it realises that the string is already in Unicode, and throws an error ("Python: Oi why are you trying to convert unicode strings into unicode?")

When you do not specify the error param, as you can see in the docs, Python is ok with converting unicode strings to unicode. If it is already unicode, it will return the unicode string without any additional decoding.

The [standard link](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) for people to help them understand what unicode is.

If you actually want to be able to perform this operation (for example, if you wanted to write code that accepts both regular strings and unicode strings), you would encode your string before you convert it back into Unicode.

Example:

```
>>> unicode(u''.encode('ascii', errors='replace'))
```

If you wanted to use a different encoding (ascii is the default):

```
>>> unicode(u''.encode('utf-8', errors='replace'), 'utf-8')
```

Comment: Your example doesn't make any sense; `encode` shouldn't generate any errors so adding an error specifier is redundant. As to why you might try converting a Unicode string to Unicode, perhaps you're writing code that wants to be forgiving in what it accepts but you need to work with the Unicode string no matter what.

Comment: The error specifier is part of the `unicode` function, not the `encode` function (Although I'm not actually sure why the poster wants an error specifier regardless). But you make a good point about forgiving code, I didn't think of that. Edited.

Comment: My point was that since `encode` will never generate any output with errors in it, it doesn't matter what you specify for `errors` and you might as well leave it off.

Comment: As I said before, the `errors` param is for the `unicode` function. It's not about the error output, but how the codec handles invalid characters. In the Python docs: "a value of 'replace' causes the official Unicode replacement character, U+FFFD, to be used to replace input characters which cannot be decoded"

Comment: I don't know how I can say this any plainer: the `unicode` function won't get any invalid characters, because `encode` won't produce any! P.S. You're taking a good answer and making it worse. You should have stopped much earlier.

Comment: Ah, I see. So what you meant to say was "encode will never generate any output with invalid characters in it", rather than "encode will never generate any output with errors in it". Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47912/discussion-between-icedtrees-and-mark-ransom)

Comment: Thanks icedtrees MarkRansom .  

Indeed, it's right there in the python docs!  _If encoding and/or errors are given, unicode() will decode the object_ . 
As @MarkRansom said "_As to why you might try converting a Unicode string to Unicode, perhaps you're writing code that wants to be forgiving in what it accepts but you need to work with the Unicode string no matter what_" .  Yes, this is exactly why I came across this unpexpected `unicode()` behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `unicode()` function is supposed to take data of type `string` and not type `unicode`:

*The unicode() constructor has the signature unicode(string[, encoding, errors]). All of its arguments should be 8-bit strings. The first argument is converted to Unicode using the specified encoding; **if you leave off the encoding argument, the ASCII encoding is used for the conversion, so characters greater than 127 will be treated as errors:***

```
>>> unicode('abcdef')
u'abcdef'
>>> s = unicode('abcdef')
>>> type(s)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> unicode('abcdef' + chr(255))    
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 6:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

`u''` is encoding the empty string (which I believe is not a character greater than 127). It should be fine without encoding arguments, but I believe `unicode` raises an error because it's not supposed to accept Unicode regularly.

I'm throwing my best guess at this one at the moment, so any corrections would be appreciated.

Comment: But if you look at his examples, he passes an empty string.

Comment: I think the question is more about why `unicode()` behaves differently when it is given an `errors` parameter vs. not.

Comment: He passes in the unicode of the empty string, which I assume is still unicode. I believe `Unicode()` is NOT supposed to take in actual Unicode type data

Comment: Yes, as @MarkRansom said.  I'm wondering why `unicode()` behaves so differently.  The inconsistent behavior based on an optional parameter is unexpected and confusing.
I'm NOT directly asking why `unicode()` should (or should not) accept `u''` in any case.  Rather, why it behaves differently for two different cases.